# How to optimize this MySQL query?

Tags: mysql, optimization

Hi can someone help me to optimize this MySQL query, it's taking very long to complete, I have set indexes correctly, but it seems that string operations are slowing this query

```
SELECT vendor_products.*, 
       (SELECT Count(*) 
        FROM   products 
        WHERE  gtin = vendor_products.gtin 
                OR gtin = Concat(0, vendor_products.gtin) 
                OR gtin = Substr(vendor_products.gtin, 2)) AS product_count 
FROM   vendor_products 
WHERE  vendor_products.vendor_id != 26 
       AND vendor_products.cost > 0 
       AND vendor_products.short_description != '' 
       AND created_at >= '2014-07-01 00:00:00' 
HAVING product_count = 0 
LIMIT  100
```

Can someone guide me and tell what I can improve?

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `vendor_products` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `vendor_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `gtin` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `sku` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `mpn` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `weight` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `inventory` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `cost` decimal(18,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000',
  `price` decimal(18,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000',
  `nav` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `lemil` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `deleted` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `short_description` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `long_description` mediumtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `vendor_products_vendor_id_index` (`vendor_id`),
  KEY `vendor_products_gtin_index` (`gtin`),
  KEY `vendor_products_sku_index` (`sku`),
  KEY `deleted` (`deleted`),
  KEY `lemil` (`lemil`),
  KEY `nav` (`nav`),
  KEY `mpn` (`mpn`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=340210 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `products` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `manufacturer_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `gtin` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `sku` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `mpn` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `new_insert` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `product_type` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `vendor_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `store_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `nav` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `lemil` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `package` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `used` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `free_shipping` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `short_description` mediumtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `full_description` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `force_msrp` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `msrp` decimal(18,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000',
  `price` decimal(18,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000',
  `old_price` decimal(18,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000',
  `product_cost` decimal(18,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000',
  `special_price` decimal(18,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000',
  `special_price_start_date` datetime DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `special_price_end_date` datetime DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `outdoor_daily_price` decimal(18,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000',
  `map_high` decimal(18,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000',
  `map_low` decimal(18,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000',
  `stock_quantity` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `inbound_stock_quantity` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `in_stock_message` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `out_of_stock_message` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `inbound_user` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `weight` decimal(18,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000',
  `length` decimal(18,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000',
  `width` decimal(18,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000',
  `height` decimal(18,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000',
  `meta_keywords` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `meta_description` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `inventory_update` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `hide_from_guests` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `published` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `published_by` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `publish_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `deleted` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `deleted_on` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `products_gtin_index` (`gtin`),
  KEY `products_sku_index` (`sku`),
  KEY `products_new_insert_index` (`new_insert`),
  KEY `products_product_type_index` (`product_type`),
  KEY `products_vendor_id_index` (`vendor_id`),
  KEY `products_store_id_index` (`store_id`),
  KEY `products_nav_index` (`nav`),
  KEY `products_lemil_index` (`lemil`),
  KEY `products_package_index` (`package`),
  KEY `products_used_index` (`used`),
  KEY `products_free_shipping_index` (`free_shipping`),
  KEY `products_price_index` (`price`),
  KEY `products_hide_from_guests_index` (`hide_from_guests`),
  KEY `products_published_index` (`published`),
  KEY `products_deleted_index` (`deleted`),
  KEY `products_manufacturer_id_index` (`manufacturer_id`),
  KEY `products_published_by_index` (`published_by`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=117624 ;
```

Comment: Give us a SHOW CREATE TABLE vendor_products\G (and products) and even some sample data - either on SQLFiddle or as a download. That would help those who wish to help you.

Comment: I have added table definitions, right now I am not able to put anything on SQLFiddle

Comment: You should post the new query as an answer. It is equivalent to the first one.

Comment: Thanks guys, I have moved the query I've proposed as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found out the solution by looking other similar questions, this query runs fast. Hopefully it will help someone that is having similar issue.

```
SELECT    vendor_products.*
FROM      vendor_products 
LEFT JOIN products a 
ON        a.gtin = vendor_products.gtin 
LEFT JOIN products b 
ON        b.gtin = Concat(0, vendor_products.gtin) 
LEFT JOIN products c 
ON        c.gtin = Substr(vendor_products.gtin, 2) 
WHERE     a.id IS NULL 
AND       b.id IS NULL 
AND       c.id IS NULL 
AND       vendor_products.vendor_id != 26 
AND       vendor_products.cost > 0 
AND       vendor_products.short_description != '' 
AND       vendor_products.created_at >= '2014-07-01 00:00:00' limit 100
```

If someone have even better solution please offer it here.

I did explain on answer query and this is the result
[image]

The explain on original question query looks like this
[image]

So there is 100.000+ more rows for search with the original approach no wonder why it was so slow.

Comment: My guess - as to why this is faster - is that you replaced the `OR` with 3 independent joins and the indexes (on the `gtin` columns) can be used more effectively, especially for the first of the left join. If you provide the `EXPLAIN` outputs for the 2 queries, we may see.

Comment: Yep you are right, there is 100.000+ rows to search with original query

Comment: Yes, the key difference in the explain plan is the `ref` column. You see a `NULL` in the original query's plan. In the 2nd query, there is an index there and a `func` (the function you have applied to the indexed column). So, the `vendor_products.gtin` index can be used against the other `gtin` index.